# the higher the altitude, the lower the molecular density of the compounds. why doesn't this apply to O, N and O3?

Tags: atmosphere

for them, behavior interference occurs from certain altitudes. What are these interferences? and why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O3 is a highly reactive molecule which is constantly being produced (by UV) at high altitude. It reacts, and disappears. It is not produced at low altitude because UV penetrates the atmosphere poorly... largely because of O3. Hence the gradient.

Ditto for the others.

Stable molecules are uniformly distributed as expected.